# Python Intersection of two Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, intersection

I need to intersect data frame. So I executed the following code. But I cannot get the result I want.

```
df1 = pd.Dataframe([
      ['psy', 180, 75],
      ['psy', 180, 75]
], columns = ['name', 'height', 'weight'])

df2 = pd.Dataframe([
      ['psy', 180, 75],
      ['df', 160, 65],
      ['ddqq', 170, 75],
      ['psy', 180, 75]
], columns = ['name', 'height', 'weight'])

print(pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner'))
```

**Output**

```
  name  height  weight
0 psy   180     75
1 psy   180     75
2 psy   180     75
3 psy   180     75
```

But I want the below results.

```
 name  height  weight
0 psy   180     75
1 psy   180     75
```

How can I get the following result? Please Tell me...

Comment: I think it is because the same name `psy` for 2 rows pandas is confused how to join. You can try by name=ing them `psy1` and `psy2` then you will get desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You can drop duplicates from one of the DataFrames. For example:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2.drop_duplicates(), how='inner')
```

Output:

```
  name  height  weight
0  psy     180      75
1  psy     180      75
```